# MomentJS gives me the wrong year, why?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm either very confused or too tired...

```
var year = 2016;
var week = 40;

var startDate = moment().year(year).week(week).day(1).startOf('day').toDate();
var endDate = moment(startDate).add(6, 'days').endOf('day').toDate();

console.log(new Date()); // Sun Jan 01 2017 00:28:44 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time) 

console.log(year, week, startDate, endDate); // 2016 40 Mon Sep 28 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time) Sun Oct 04 2015 23:59:59 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time) <-- look the year, 2015!!
```

[image: Screenshot of the console output]

**What I want is just a date range from week 40 from year 2016**, but it gives that week from year 2015. Why?

**Edit: To reproduce the problem you need a finnish locale for MomentJS.**

Also, there is a difference if you call moment().year().week() or moment().week().year()

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>t</title>    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/locale/fi.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
    var year = 2016;
    var week = 40;
    document.write(moment().format());
    document.write("<br>");
    var startDate = moment().year(year).week(week).day(1).startOf('day').toDate();
    var endDate = moment(startDate).add(6, 'days').endOf('day').toDate();

    document.write(new Date());
    document.write("<br>");
    document.write('startDate = '+startDate);
    document.write("<br>");
    document.write('endDate = '+endDate);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

P.S. It worked properly in the gone-away 2016, but since 2017 it gives that odd 2015.
P.P.S. Happy New Year ! :)

Comment: If you are no longer having an issue, please delete the question.

Comment: @Erik Looks like it's 2017 that introduced this problem, not vice versa. Nice job, 2017 ;)

Comment: @ErikPhilips That's true, you need at least a finnish locale to reproduce this. This was suprise for me too. I'll keep this open a while, ok?

Comment: Might be worth to file a bug report as I noticed an issue when the Finnish locale was used as well, not the same issue as you but a difference of a week.

Comment: @haykokoryun u are right